# Can't play CD on fedora: no medium found on /dev/sr0

Tags: audio-cd

When I insert a DVD into the drive on my PC under Fedora 33, **vlc** opens the disk automatically and begins to play it.  When I insert a CD (audio or data), the drive spins up and the light blinks, but the disk fails to automount. The disk doesn't appear in **Rhythmbox** or **Files**.  When I try to mount with `mount /dev/sr0 /tmp`, I get `mount: /tmp: no medium found on /dev/sr0`.  I *can* successfully `eject` the drive.  I have installed all the recommended gstreamer plugins and can see no obvious errors in the following commands

```
$ lsblk
$ lspci
$ dmesg | egrep -i --color 'cdrom|dvd|cd/rw|writer'
$ cdrecord -prcap dev=/dev/cdrom
$ ls -l /dev/sr0
```

The audio CDs play fine in another dvd drive on my ancient laptop.  I've recently upgraded from Fedora 32 so all the libraries are up to date.  As far as I can recall, I've never bothered playing CDs from this machine.  It's been a long time since I've had to deal with CD/DVD issues, so there could be something in the last 5-10 years that I haven't kept up with.  I'm still coming up to speed with systemd.  ;)

The only errors I can spot are from `journalctl /dev/sr0`

```
Apr 09 11:57:52 corvus kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: AHCI 0001.0300 32 slots 5 ports 6 Gbps 0x5 impl SATA mode
kernel: ahci 0000:00:1f.2: flags: 64bit ncq pm led clo pio slum part ems apst 
kernel: scsi host2: ahci
kernel: scsi 2:0:0:0: CD-ROM            hp       DVD-RAM UJ8E1    4H01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi3-mmc drive: 24x/24x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 5
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE cmd_age=0s
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 Sense Key : Not Ready [current] 
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 Add. Sense: Incompatible medium installed
kernel: sr 2:0:0:0: [sr0] tag#23 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
```

```
# wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sr0'  rwrw-- : 'hp' 'DVD-RAM UJ8E1'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The output of cd-info

```
cd-info version 2.1.0 x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
CD location   : /dev/cdrom
CD driver name: GNU/Linux
   access mode: IOCTL

Vendor                      : hp      
Model                       : DVD-RAM UJ8E1   
Revision                    : 4H01
Hardware                                  : CD-ROM or DVD
Can eject                                 : Yes
Can close tray                            : Yes
Can disable manual eject                  : Yes
Can select juke-box disc                  : No

Can set drive speed                       : No
Can read multiple sessions (e.g. PhotoCD) : Yes
Can hard reset device                     : Yes

Reading....
  Can read Mode 2 Form 1                  : Yes
  Can read Mode 2 Form 2                  : Yes
  Can read (S)VCD (i.e. Mode 2 Form 1/2)  : Yes
  Can read C2 Errors                      : Yes
  Can read IRSC                           : Yes
  Can read Media Channel Number (or UPC)  : Yes
  Can play audio                          : Yes
  Can read CD-DA                          : Yes
  Can read CD-R                           : Yes
  Can read CD-RW                          : Yes
  Can read DVD-ROM                        : Yes

Writing....
  Can write CD-RW                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-R                         : Yes
  Can write DVD-RAM                       : Yes
  Can write DVD-RW                        : No
  Can write DVD+RW                        : No
__________________________________

Disc mode is listed as: Error in getting information
++ WARN: error in ioctl CDROMREADTOCHDR: No medium found

cd-info: Can't get first track number. I give up.
```

The OS is GNU/Linux 5.11.11-200.fc33.x86_64.

Where should I look next and what issues should I be thinking of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDs and DVDs require different wavelengths of light. In your drive there is one laser for CD, another for DVD. My guess is the one for CD is dead. Or some other component used exclusively for CDs is dead, it makes no difference in practice.

I used to have a drive that stopped reading CDs while still being able to read DVDs.

Just in case check the drive with another computer and/or OS, if you can. I don't expect surprises though. For many years operating systems have been able to read CDs out of the box, they still can. If the physical interface between the drive and the rest of your hardware was to blame, you wouldn't be able to read DVDs.

General conclusion: if a drive reads DVDs but fails to read CDs (or vice versa) then the problem is most likely with the drive.

The drive in question is faulty. Use another one.

Comment: I wouldn't have thought of that given that the DVD works.  thanks ;)